# Wild cards in SML

Tags: sml

```
  1 fun max(a,b,c) =                                                                
  2     if a > b andalso a > c then a                                               
  3     else if b > a andalso b > c then b                                          
  4     else c                                                                      
  5 
  6                                                                                 
  6 val x = max(1,_,3);
```

I wrote a max function in SML that takes three numbers. It works just fine if I input 3 integers. However, if I give the function a wild card, it throws the following exception: `max.sml:6.15 Error: syntax error: replacing  WILD with  EQUALOP`

Why is this?

Comment: What would you expect that line to do if it did work?

Comment: sepp2k's answer is the correct one. If you would like to implement a *max* function for any number of integers, look into using a parameter of type `int list`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wild cards are used for pattern matching only. They can not be used as expressions as they do not evaluate to a value.